# What is the $i$th Chern character $\mathrm{ch}_i$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, notation, complex-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

$\newcommand{\ch}{\mathrm{ch}}$We define the Chern character of $E$ a rank $r$ locally free sheaf on a nonsingular projective variety as 
$$ \ch(E)  = \sum_{i=1}^r e^{a_i} $$
where the $a_i$ are formal symbols arising from the Chern polynomial 
$ c_t(E) = \prod_{i=1}^r (1+a_it)$. The Chern character can be given more explicitly by
$$ \ch(E)  = r + c_1 + \frac{1}{2}(c_1^2 - 2c_2) + \frac{1}{6}(c_1^3-3c_1c_2 + 3c_3) + \cdots $$
where $r=\mathrm{rk}(E)$, $c_i = c_i(E)$ are the $i$th Chern classes, and $c_i =0$ if $i > r$.

I've seen the term $i$*th Chern character* denoted $\ch_i$ being used and I was wondering what the definition of it is? I've searched through a few books but have had no luck, though I've seen things like $\ch = (\ch_0, \dots, \ch_n)$ written down. My guess would be that $\ch_i(E)$ is the sum of all of the $i$th Chern classes $c_i$ appearing in the formula for $\ch(E)$ - would this be the correct interpretation?

Comment: The Chern character can be thought of as an element of the ring $\mathbf Q[c_1,\ldots,c_r]$, which has a natural grading defined by $\operatorname{deg}(c_i)=i$. The $i$-th Chern character is then the degree-$i$ homogeneous part of $ch(E)$: in other words, the $i$-th homogeneous part of the expansion you wrote. So for example $\operatorname{ch}_1=c_1$, and $\operatorname{ch}_3=\frac{1}{6}(c_1^3-3c_1c_2+3c_3)$, and so on.

Comment: Great - thank you!